# Visits during the last 2 years

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list with users and the dates of their last visit. For every time they visit, I want to know how many times they visited over the last 2 years.

```
    # Create toy example    
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np


    date_range = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01'), 
    pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01'), freq='D')
    date_range = np.random.choice(date_range, 8)

    visits = {'user': list(np.repeat(1, 4)) + list(np.repeat(2, 4)) ,
              'time': list(date_range)}
    df = pd.DataFrame(visits)
    df.sort_values(by = ['user', 'time'], axis = 0)
    df = spark.createDataFrame(df).repartition(1).cache()
    df.show()
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
    time    user     nr_visits_during_2_previous_years
0   2010-02-27  1       0
2   2012-02-21  1       1
3   2013-04-30  1       1
1   2013-06-20  1       2
6   2010-06-23  2       0
4   2011-10-19  2       1
5   2011-11-10  2       2 
7   2014-02-06  2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you create a dataframe with these values and you need to check for visits after `2015-01-01`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

df = spark.createDataFrame([("2014-02-01", "1"),("2015-03-01", "2"),("2017-12-01", "3"),
    ("2014-05-01", "2"),("2016-10-12", "1"),("2016-08-21", "1"),
    ("2017-07-01", "3"),("2015-09-11", "1"),("2016-08-24", "1")
    ,("2016-04-05", "2"),("2014-11-19", "3"),("2016-03-11", "3")], ["date", "id"])
```

Now, you need to change your date column to `DateType` from `StringType` and then filter rows for which user visited after `2015-01-01`.

```
df2 = df.withColumn("date",f.to_date('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df3 = df2.where(df2.date >= f.lit('2015-01-01'))
```

Last part, just use groupby on `id` column and use `count` to get the number of visits by a user after `2015-01-01`

```
df3.groupby('id').count().show()
+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  3|    3|
|  1|    4|
|  2|    2|
+---+-----+
```